# Python strong password validator ( with unit test )

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

Lately, I was studying the concept of unit testing in python, so I have decided to write a imperative strong password validator ( checker ) and also attach a unit test to it.

I would like to know if there is any recommendation for improving this code, Thanks!

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


"""
KhodeNima's unit test learning package. | 23/11/9
"""


import string


ascii_lowercase_letters = string.ascii_lowercase
ascii_uppercase_letters = string.ascii_uppercase
ascii_numbers = string.digits


def is_master_password(literal: str):
    """Chekcs if a string literal have the requirements of a masterpasssword.

    Args:
        string (str): The string literal.

    Raises:
        ValueError: If invalid argument is passed for any parameter.
    """

    if not isinstance(literal, str):
        argument_type = type(literal).__name__
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid argument type passed for the parameter: string | Expected: 'str' | Not: {argument_type}")
    

    allowed_characters = ''.join([ascii_lowercase_letters, ascii_uppercase_letters, ascii_numbers])
    min_password_length = 5
    max_password_length = 20
    string_length = len(literal)
    valid_characters_count = 0

    has_upper_case = False
    has_lower_case = False
    has_digit = False
    

    if string_length < min_password_length:
        return False

    if string_length > max_password_length:
       return False


    for character in literal:

        if character in allowed_characters:
            valid_characters_count += 1


    for character in literal:

        if all([has_digit, has_upper_case, has_lower_case]):
            break
        
        if character.isdigit():
            has_digit = True
        
        if character.isupper():
            has_upper_case = True

        if character.islower():
            has_lower_case = True

        

    if not valid_characters_count == string_length or not all([has_digit, has_lower_case, has_upper_case]):
        return False
    
    return True



print(is_master_password("Reedwolf13"))
```

**unit_test.py**

```
"""
KhodeNima's Unit test training package | 2023/11/9
"""


import unittest
from main import (
    is_master_password
)


class MasterPasswordExaminerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    The main program test case
    """

    def test_character_validation_check(self):
        """Does the program character checking system work correctly?
        """

        self.assertEqual(is_master_password("!-*&%#@$()"), False)
        self.assertEqual(is_master_password('Redwolf1'), True)

    def test_length_validation_check(self):
        """Does the program validate the password length correctly?
        """

        self.assertEqual(is_master_password('Jsf3'), False)
        self.assertEqual(is_master_password('mnbRDSAQOPJK123986532nm'), False)

    def test_requirement_check(self):
        """Does the program validates the password requirements correcly? (1 Uppercase L, 1 Lowercase L, 1 Digit)
        """

        self.assertEqual(is_master_password("Redwolf1"), True)
        self.assertEqual(is_master_password("Redwolf"), False)
        self.assertEqual(is_master_password("redwolf1"), False)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I wouln't put your personal details in your profile. You don't have much to gain having the informaton in your profile. Anyway you're lucky Iran's not in the EU otherwise [your account would be have to be removed from the platform](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age).

Comment: why do you have a max length? why do you not allow special characters? why are all those rules hard-coded? where do they come from?

Comment: (also, how does the caller know how to fix the "invalid" password they tested?)

Comment: @njzk2 Greetings sir/madam. Fortunately these rules don't have a official guide or attendant and they are not genuinely certificated, these rules were set for training purpose only.

Answer (score 13):

## standard libraries are, umm, standard

```
ascii_lowercase_letters = string.ascii_lowercase
ascii_uppercase_letters = string.ascii_uppercase
ascii_numbers = string.digits
```

It's hard to see how these renames improve readability
or maintainability.

For each [RHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sides_of_an_equation)
expression I already know what it means,
or it's self explanatory, or I can look it up.
Since it's part of a standard library,
I know "there's nothing up my sleeve", no tricks, no gotchas.
That's not true for the three aliases,
unless I refer back to view their definition.

Also, the `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is odd,
given that UTF8 has been standard for a bunch
of cPython interpreter versions in recent years.
Recommend you delete it.

---

## meaningful identifier

```
def is_master_password(literal: str):
```

I found this signature slightly confusing,
as it made me think of this (which you clearly weren't saying):

```
from typing import Literal

def is_master_password(s: literal['foo', 'bar']):
```

Recommend you call a spade a spade:

```
def is_master_password(password: str):
```

Also, the function seems to have the wrong name.
The docstring explains it should be called `def is_valid_master_password`.

```
    Args:
        string (str): The string literal.
```

I don't understand what you wrote.
We don't see a parameter named `string` in the signature.
Please delete this fluff,
as it does not add any information
and it is in danger of getting out of sync / has gotten out of sync
with the code it describes.

```
    Raises:
        ValueError: If invalid argument is passed for any parameter.
    """

    if not isinstance(literal, str):
```

Recommend you delete all this fluff.
The signature already has a very nice type annotation,
so `mypy` will flag any attempted shenanigans.
And duck typing will offer a pretty clear
diagnostic stack trace for bad input when we attempt
any one of these:

- len( ... )
- character in ...
- .isdigit()

As written this just isn't a very pythonic predicate.

```
    max_password_length = 20
```

I don't understand why offering 21 characters would be insecure.
This line needs a comment so we can trace it back to a requirements document.

---

## premature optimization

```
        if all([has_digit, has_upper_case, has_lower_case]):
            break
```

Please delete this.
It is distracting, and it does not appreciably speed things up.

May as well merge the boolean ops with the "valid" counting loop.

---

## standard asserts

Expressions like this are slightly odd:

```
        self.assertEqual(is_master_password("Redwolf1"), True)
```

Using `assertEqual` is *great* in many contexts.
But here, it would be more natural to `self.assertTrue( ... )`.

Comment: If you want to keep the ascii in there you might want to do `import string as ascii`

Comment: @Daviid I'd never let code with standard library name aliasing pass my review. `import string as ascii` reads like "we all know what `string` module does, let's make reading this code a bit more challenging".

Comment: Another minor suggestion is to use `string.ascii_letters` instead of concatenating `string.ascii_lowercase` and `string.ascii_uppercase`

Answer (score 5):

## Style

Your code is readable, well documented, and mostly follows conventions, nice.

My only nitpicks here is that you use `snake_case` for constants, where these should be `ALL_CAPS` in order to easily identify them as constants (`MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH`, for example) and that you use a bit too much vertical whitespace for my taste (but too much is better than too little).

Constants should also be defined at the top level, right after imports.

## Tests

I appreciate that you include unit tests, using a proper testing framework.

A couple of remarks here:

- improve your code coverage: you don't test if missing lowercase characters triggers a rejection
- Split your test cases so that each one tests one path: if you make changes to the function being tested and a test breaks, it will be much easier to figure out where you went wrong

## Executed statement

The line `print(is_master_password("Reedwolf13"))` at the bottom of your script gets executed each time it is loaded, including after import. You can see its output when running tests. Not good. You should put it behind a `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard, or, since your code is tested anyway, remove it.

## Return early

You already return early after length checks. You could go all the way and return early after checking for invalid characters.

## Logic issues

When checking for invalid characters, your logic seems convoluted: you count valid characters, then compare with the total number of characters. I feel it's more straightforward to check if any character is invalid:

```
any(character not in ALLOWED_CHARACTERS for character in password)
```

Similarly, you can save explicitly looping and keeping track of flags by using `any` checks for character sets.

## Naming

I find the name `is_master_password` confusing: I would expect this function to tell me if the password matches *the* master password. I find `validate_password` to be more descriptive.

You should name your modules to reflect what they do, something like `password validator.py` and `password validator tests.py` are much more descriptive.

## Sample code

Here is my take on the problem, also addressing issues noted in @J_H's answer.

password_validator.py:

```
"""
Utility module to check password validity
"""


from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits


MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 5
MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 20
ALLOWED_CHARACTERS = ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase + digits


def is_valid_password(password: str) -> bool:
    """
    Checks if a password matches the following requirements:
        * is at least MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH characters long
        * is at most MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH characters long
        * contains only allowed characters
        * includes uppercase, lowercase, and digit characters

    Parameters
    ----------
    password : str
        the password to validate.

    Returns
    -------
    bool
        True if the password id valid, false otherwise.
    """

    if len(password) < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
        return False

    if len(password) > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
       return False

    if any(character not in ALLOWED_CHARACTERS for character in password):
        return False
    
    return (any(character in ascii_lowercase for character in password)
            and any(character in ascii_uppercase for character in password)
            and any(character in digits for character in password))
```

password_validator_tests.py:

```
"""
Tests for the password validator module
"""


import unittest

from password_validator import is_valid_password


class MasterPasswordExaminerTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_valid_passwords(self):
        """Should accepts a valid password"""
        self.assertTrue(is_valid_password("Redwolf1"))
        self.assertTrue(is_valid_password("abAB1"))
        self.assertTrue(is_valid_password("0123456789aAbBcCdDeE"))
        
    def test_password_too_short(self):
        """Should reject a too short password"""
        self.assertFalse(is_valid_password("aAB1"))
        self.assertFalse(is_valid_password(""))
        
    def test_password_too_long(self):
        """Should reject a too long password"""
        self.assertFalse(is_valid_password("0123456789aAbBcCdDeEf"))
        
    def test_character_validation_check(self):
        """Should reject a password with invalid characters"""
        self.assertFalse(is_valid_password("Redwolf1&"))
        self.assertFalse(is_valid_password("Redwolf1ù"))

    def test_includes_characters_from_each_set(self):
        """Should reject a password missing a character from each category"""
        self.assertFalse(is_valid_password("edwolf1"))
        self.assertFalse(is_valid_password("Redwolf"))
        self.assertFalse(is_valid_password("REDWOLF1"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

## Going further

These password validation rules are very weak. It is good practice to use longer passwords, with a larger character set, and this password validator is not useful in real life.

If you want to go further, you might want to improve your logic to:

- accept longer passwords
- accept other character sets
- ensure the password contains characters from X sets out of Y
- base validation on entropy instead of a rigid set of rules, allowing long passphrases (`correct horse battery staple`) as well as shorter, random strings (`{@C54UCiY#M:**fP`)

Comment: I think too little vertical whitespace is far better than too much. Easier to see where the blocks are.

Answer (score 5):

Please read this as an addition to two existing answers, I agree with almost all points made there.

## Whitespace

You may like excessive vertical whitespace, it's your choice. But in this case it's a choice that violates formatting standard ([PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#blank-lines), link to relevant section):

> Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.

Most existing formatters (black, ruff, autopep8) will deny more than one line inside a function. And it's generally good thing to do: when you split all the lines into separate "blocks" 1-2 lines each, it's becoming more difficult to read. And please, definitely no blank lines immediately after `for` loop - indentation makes the following line sufficiently distinct.

## Docstring

A nitpick in addition to answer by @J_H

Prescribe, do not describe. The first sentence of a docstring [should](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings) be prescriptive, like

> Check if a string meets the requirements for a master password.

## Booleans are good as booleans!

You have the following:

```
if not valid_characters_count == string_length or not all([has_digit, has_lower_case, has_upper_case]):
    return False
return True
```

While it could be just

```
return (
    valid_characters_count == string_length
    and all([has_digit, has_lower_case, has_upper_case])
)
```

(and definitely not `if not x == y`, there is a fancy syntax sugar for that called "not equal" and denoted as `x != y`)

## Entrypoint

You have a shebang on top of your script. It is a good thing to have in **scripts**, but not at all in library parts. If you're going to allow using this as a script, that's OK - then make it actually usable as a script. Probably you want a script that can read a password and report its quality by exit code (0 for OK, 1 for insufficiently strong). You can use `argparse` for it to get help and validation for free.

```py
def _read_args(source: list[str]):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog="check_password.py",
        description="Utility for admin password validation",
    )
    parser.add_argument("password", help="The password to check")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-q",
        "--quiet",
        action="store_false",
        dest="verbose",
        help="Omit output",
    )
    return parser.parse_args(source)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = _read_args(sys.argv[1:])
    is_strong = is_strong_master_password(args.password)
    if args.verbose:
        if is_strong:
            print("Validated successfully")
        else:
            print("Validation failed", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1 - is_strong)
```

I'm omitting the return type above for brevity, you may use a Protocol to make this fully typed:

```py
from typing import Protocol


class _CommandArguments(Protocol):
    password: str
    verbose: bool


def _read_args(source: list[str]) -> _CommandArguments:
    ...  # Implementation follows
```

Alternatively, you can remove the shebang if it's not going to be a script.

## Reference code

Here's what (roughly) I would have done with these requirements (note that in real life 5-char ASCII password can not be secure):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Utility script for admin password validation."""

import argparse
import string
import sys
from typing import Final, Protocol

MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH: Final = 5
MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH: Final = 20
ALLOWED_CHARACTERS: Final = set(
    "".join([string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase, string.digits])
)


def is_strong_master_password(password: str) -> bool:
    """Check if a string meets the requirements for a master password."""

    string_length = len(password)
    if string_length < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
        return False
    if string_length > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
        return False

    if set(password) - ALLOWED_CHARACTERS:
        # Contains characters outside of allowed range.
        return False

    has_upper_case = False
    has_lower_case = False
    has_digit = False
    for character in password:
        if character.isdigit():
            has_digit = True
        if character.isupper():
            has_upper_case = True
        if character.islower():
            has_lower_case = True

    return all([has_digit, has_lower_case, has_upper_case])

...  # Entrypoint code goes here
```

Yes, `set` building costs more than iteration, but less than you implementation: your original code will check up to (26+26+10) characters on every iteration, while set difference does not have to go this far. We build a set in `O(n log n)` with `n` being a password length, but it's still nothing with any real-life length constraints. This code is likely not something performance-critical, and so brevity and clean look should be more important.